# jQuery bind on change of length

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I have a table that is being updated by Ajax. I want to do something when new data is added to it, but since the change is in appearance, it should be done by the preloaded JS rather than Ajax returned JS.

I am looking for something like `$('table tr').length.change( ... )`, So I can do something like this

```
$('table tr').length.change( function() {
  if ($('table tr').length>1) $('table').show() else $('table').hide()
}
```

The Ajax-returned JS will do something like this (say in Rails)

```
$('table').append('<tr> <td><%= @person.name %></td> <td><%= @person.age %></td> </tr>')
```

(in Rails this will be in some `/app/views/container_name/method_name.js.erb`)

Comment: Why are you not doing it where you are updating the table? That would be a log simpler.

Comment: @Mohayemin, it could be done there, but I want to know if there is a way to separate the insertion of the content from the layout and presentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a [pub-sub](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Publish%E2%80%93subscribe_pattern) approach.

```
$('table')
   .append('<tr> <td><%= @person.name %></td> <td><%= @person.age %></td> </tr>')
   .trigger('tableModified');
```

Then in your layout/design,

```
$('table').on('tableModified',function(){
    if ($('tr', this).length>1) $(this).show() else $(this).hide()
});
```

This way your table code doesn't have to be aware of your layout/design or anything else that may need to know when the table is modified.

Answer (score 1):

I used a jQuery plugin called `watch` in a project way back in similiar circumstances. I had to track a lot more attributes, but it worked nicely for me:

http://darcyclarke.me/dev/watch/

Comment: looks neat! It seems that watch looks for css attributes. Can it use number of rows?

Comment: not that i ever tried it, but you could watch the height and use `$('#myTable tr').length` in the callback, couldn't you?

Answer (score 0):

Just after append statement try show-hide statement.

```
$('table')
   .append('<tr> <td><%= @person.name %></td> <td><%= @person.age %></td> </tr>');

if( $('table tbody tr').length > 1 ) {
   $('table').show();
} else {
   $('table').hide()
}
```

**Note**:

`$('table tr').length.change(..)` is not valid approach. Because, `.change()` in an event handler that works for `input, select` elements those wrapped within `$()` i.e for jQuery Object.

For example:

```
$('select').change()`, `$('input').change()
```

Moreover, `.length` does not return a jQuery object. So you can't use `.change()` with `.length` and its not needed at all.

Comment: I could do that, but I want to separate the data insertion and layout/presentation design issues.